# Microservice JWT + LDAP authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, jwt, microservices

I am building a microservices project in which on api gateway I wants to do authentication using JWT and Ldap. Is it feasible or just jwt authenticatino will be enough for my authentication. What will be the benefits of using ldap if I will go with ldap and jwt both.